# How to create a function where if the R version is older than 3.5, it gives a warning?

Tags: r

I currently have the following code to see if the current R version is not equal to 3.5.0. However, I would like to change it so that if someone has a R version older than 3.5.0, it gives a warning to update R. Because 3.5.0 is not "less than" 3.4.0, etc, I am having issues creating a boolean command, since the computer doesnt recognize 3.4.0 as being "less than" 3.5.0. Is there a way to facilitate this?

```
if(strsplit(version[['version.string']], ' ')[[1]][3] != '3.5.0'){
  print("Warning: Update R")
}
```

Comment: You can either change your version string to a number or do something like: `if(strsplit(version[['version.string']], ' ')[[1]][3] < '3.5.0'){
  print("Warning: Update R")
}`

Comment: Actually `'3.4.0' < '3.5.0'`, `'3.4.9' < '3.5.0'`  does return `TRUE` but I think you still need some stricter checks.

Comment: What about remove the dots `as.numeric(gsub(".", "", substring(version[['version.string']], 11, 15), fixed = TRUE)) < 350`

Comment: @Clemsang What does `fixed=TRUE` do?

Comment: Take the dots as dots in regular expressions, otherwise it is evaluated as any character. Fixed allows to have dot as a dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform version number like `3.5.0` to `350` by removing dots. This way you can easily compare current and target version :

```
if(gsub(".", "", strsplit(version[['version.string']], ' ')[[1]][3], fixed = TRUE) < '350'){
  print("Warning: Update R")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The C interface has a nice convienence function to do this.  You can see how it's defined:

```
#define R_VERSION 197890
#define R_NICK "Eggshell Igloo"
#define R_Version(v,p,s) (((v) * 65536) + ((p) * 256) + (s))
```

So you can do something like this:

```
#include <Rversion.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool isVersionOutdated() {
#if R_VERSION < R_Version(3, 5, 1)
  return true;
#else
  return false;
#endif
}
```

R side:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("test.cpp")
isVersionOutdated()
[1] FALSE
```